# How to rebase commits in Git (Github)

Tags: git, github, rebase

Lets suppose I have some fork of original repo on Github. I cant commit directly to original repo but can create pull request and then my boss can merge that with master.

So I have created pull request, then added another commit with `git push` and another...

```
commit 4b4c5adb07b5faec478c2cefa06d1cec57047b1c
Author: me
Date:   Fri Dec 18 16:34:52 2015 +0200

    - commit 4

commit 09976ccb977b9d26cdaafb9ce10a4873ce0aa72s
Author: me
Date:   Thu Dec 17 18:19:44 2015 +0200

    - commit 3


commit 959ecb664a54374569eaeda86d5ab5fcbdc1cd26
Author: me
Date:   Tue Dec 15 09:09:35 2015 +0000

    - commit 2

commit c0d5cd88ac9e8e05ac71e26cb090392a6e53f42f
Author: me
Date:   Fri Dec 11 16:59:42 2015 +0200

    - commit 1
```

So now I want to merge these commits into one. I've tried googling but don't fully understand how to do that correct. Maybe somebody can help me?

Comment: Did you look into "interactive rebase"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
$ git rebase --interactive <commit_id>
```

(where commit_id is your commit id for the commit just before commit 1.
You will get the following on your screen -

```
pick 7ebd974 commit 1
pick cd6d73f commit 2
pick f1d3e12 commit 3
pick 37f22bd commit 4

# Rebase 4ae22a2..37f22bd onto 4ae22a2 (4 command(s))
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

Edit this and replace pick with squash for commits 2, 3 and 4 -

```
pick 7ebd974 commit 1
squash cd6d73f commit 2
squash f1d3e12 commit 3
squash 37f22bd commit 4

# Rebase 4ae22a2..37f22bd onto 4ae22a2 (4 command(s))
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

After saving the changes you will get the following on your screen -

```
# This is a combination of 4 commits.
# The first commit's message is:
commit 1

# This is the 2nd commit message:

commit 2

# This is the 3rd commit message:

commit 3

# This is the 4th commit message:

commit 4

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# Date:      Sat Dec 19 04:00:27 2015 +0530
#
# rebase in progress; onto 4ae22a2
```

Now finally write the appropriate commit message and comment out the other commit messages by using a # before them -

```
# This is a combination of 4 commits.
# The first commit's message is:

final commit

#commit 1

# This is the 2nd commit message:

#commit 2

# This is the 3rd commit message:

#commit 3

# This is the 4th commit message:

#commit 4

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
```

After all this you can do a force push to make your local changes get reflected on your remote -
`git push --force <remote_name> <branch_name>`

Comment: Thanks. It works OK when you have not pushed changes to your own remote repo. But if you have created pull request and then commited few times - I have get yet another commit. But I want to merge few commits into one.

Comment: do a force push after doing all this, force push always helps in rewriting commits on your remote repo. ```git push --force <remote_name> <branch_name>```

Comment: Everything fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As you already pushed your separate commits it's not wise to squash these commits into one. You would have to push again with force as Github doesn't really know what you did.

With rebase, your commits can be squashed into the sha c0d5cd88ac9e8e05ac71e26cb090392a6e53f42f, the repository on Github knows about the next commits and so it will not allow a push unless you force it.

The problem could become that your boss already pulled your pull request and now his local branch would be totally out of sync with the one on github.

If you really want to do this:

1. Remove your pull request.
2. Locally: git rebase -i c0d5cd88ac9e8e05ac71e26cb090392a6e53f42f
3. Follow on screen instructions.
4. Push to github again
5. Create new PR